# Foreign Key Android DATABASE

Tags: android, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm confused about the correct usage and implementation of the "Foreign KEY" in the SQLite Database in Android.

I created a DB with several relations, as following:

```
CREATE TABLE "food" (
`_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
`description`   TEXT,
`category_id`   INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(`category_id`) REFERENCES food(_id) )

CREATE TABLE `category` (
`_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`cagory_name`   TEXT NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE "favourites" (
`_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`id_favourite`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(`id_favourite`) REFERENCES food ( _id ))
```

As you can see, there are 3 tables and the _id of "food" is the foreign key connecting the table "category" and "favourites".

Now, in Android I don't see happening ANYTHING that proves that I created such a relation among tables. Do I miss some declaration to make it effective?
How does it work in Android?

Answer (score 0):

The category_id foreign key reference seems odd. 
Is there a reason it's:

```
FOREIGN KEY(`category_id`) REFERENCES food(_id)
```

and not

```
FOREIGN KEY(`category_id`) REFERENCES category(_id)
```

To make sure foreign key constraints are enforced, in SQLite run

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

See http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html for documentation.

Comment: Yes, you're right it's a mistake. But apart that, I still don't see the clear usage of foreign key within Android

Comment: Ah I see, are you testing the contraint and it's failing those tests? Or do you just not see a need for it?

Comment: I'm testing it and I don't see any differences if I add the FOREIGN KEY attribute, thus I assume I miss some piece of code to implement in Android Studio...
For example: i can add references to _id that doesn't exist and the App still working without problems...

Comment: See edited answer to ensure the foreign key constraints are enforced.